# Vue - how to get a file to a hidden input field

Tags: vue.js

I am currently previewing an image, but would also like to actually return somehow the file to my form, so that I can later submit it in the backend, but not sure how to do that?

This is my component:

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-if="!image">
    <h2>Select an image</h2>
    <input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <img :src="image" />
    <button @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
    <input type="file" v-bind:value="{ file }" style="display:none">
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            image: '',
            formData:new FormData()
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onFileChange: function onFileChange(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
                return;
            this.createImage(files[0]);
            this.formData.append('file', files[0]);
        },
        createImage: function createImage(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var vm = this;
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                vm.image = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
        removeImage: function removeImage(e) {
            this.image = '';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried with adding `formData:new FormData()` to data function and then appending the file to formData object like this:

```
this.formData.append('file', files[0]);
```

But I get an error:

> formData is not defined

Comment: did you solve the issue? I'm facing the same but didn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think the error caused by `v-bind:value="{ file }` , you should remove it, and it will work:

```
<input type="file" style="display:none">
```

You can't use `v-model = "file"` to get the file data, and what you have done with `this.formData.append('file', files[0]);` is the right way to get the data, if you want to get the data in the scope of your components, you can do something like this:

```
    data() {
      return {
        image: '',
        formData:new FormData(),
        file: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
    onFileChange: function onFileChange(e) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
            return;
        this.createImage(files[0]);
        this.formData.append('file', files[0]);
        this.file = files[0];
    }

    ....
```

reference:

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-using-v-model-with-input-typefile?page=1
- http://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Comment: I did as suggested but I don't get any file in my controller when I do dd(Input::all());